# @ManagedProperty on #{param} does not work in @ViewScoped

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, view-scope, http-request-parameters

My bean has this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BookBean implements Serializable
{       
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}") // does not work with @ViewScoped
    private String id;

    public void init()
    {
        id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id")
        if (id != null) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + id);
            currentBook = bookService.find(id);
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void post()
    {   
        // does not work with @ViewScoped
        System.out.println("ID: " + id);
        currentBook = bookService.find(id);    
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    } 

    public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And the destination Facelet has this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bookBean.id}">
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bookBean.init}" />
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
```

Through testing, I've noticed that `@ManagedProperty` and `@PostConstruct` only work with `@RequestScoped` bean.

For `@ViewScoped` bean, I found that I had to do this `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id")` to get the value of the `id` parameter.

Is this the only way to get a request parameter's value with `@ViewScoped`?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The view scope is broader than the request scope. The [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) can only set properties which have the same or broader scope as compared to the managed bean's scope.

Just keep using [`<f:viewParam>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) with [`<f:event>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/event.html). You should only not nest them in each other.

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bookBean.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bookBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BookBean implements Serializable {

    private String id;

    public void init() {
        if (id != null) {
            currentBook = bookService.find(id);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `<f:viewParam>` will set the request parameter and the `<f:event>` will execute the listener method after setting of those parameters.

The `@PostConstruct` works fine on view scoped beans as well, but it only runs directly after bean's construction and all dependency injections are been set (such as `@ManagedProperty`, `@EJB`, `@Inject`, `@Resource`, etc). The `<f:viewParam>` however sets the property thereafter, so it's not available in `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: @BalusC: That didn't work for me. The value of `id` returns null.

Comment: Works fine here. What JSF impl/version? What appserver? I created a quick testcase with Mojarra 2.0.4 on Tomcat 7.0.11 and it works fine by calling `test.xhtml?id=123`.

Comment: Mojarra 2.1.0 that comes with Glassfish 3.1. My getter/setter are created for the `id` field = so technically, it should pick up the value set by the `f:viewParam>` tag

Comment: Are you sure that you've fixed the incorrect nesting? If you nest it, then the `f:event` will be called before `f:viewParam`.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, I forgot to move the f:event tag after the `<f:metadata>` tag. My bad. I've learnt something new today. Can I suggest that future JSF spec be written by you, Bauke. You have a gifted skill in that you can translate complex documentation to easy-to-understand demonstrated code examples. I've been to many JSF 2 sites already, including the ones written by Sun's folks, but I can't make head or tail on some of their explanation of the new JSF 2 features like `<f:viewParam>`. You, on the other hand, make it look so simple. You have my respect because of this ability...

Comment: Ah thanks for reporting back. I was already busy installing GF 3.1 (I have only 3.0.1 here). You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method for getting a request parameter inside a ViewScoped bean.  This would be what #{param.device} would get in a RequestScoped bean.   This has the advantage of not requiring any tags in the presentation layer.

```
private int deviceID;
public int getDeviceID() {
    if (deviceID == 0) {
        String s = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
                getRequestParameterMap().get("device");
        try {
            deviceID = Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }
    }
    return deviceID;
}
```